# Scheme (DrRacket) - read-line doesn't stop for input at second attempt

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I have prompt user for 2 values to be stored in 2 different variables as follows:

```
(define (promptUser)
  (define varA 'a)
  (define varB 0)

  (display "Value or hit q/Q to terminate: ") 
  (set! varA  (read-line))

  (cond
       ((or (string=? varA  "q") (string=? varA  "Q")))
       (else
           (display "Value for b: ")
           (set! varB (read))
           (promptUser)
       )
   )  
)
```

As you can see, when I call `(promptUser)` the first time, it actually stops at `(read-line)` to wait for user input, but for some reason the call at `(promptUser)` actually skips through for the first user input and jumps directly into `else` case under `cond`

Example of error as below: 
[image]

It doesn't stop for varA's input.

Can someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some problem with:

```
(set! varB (read))
```

When testing in drracket 'read' gets everything until separator, that is space or new line. I can guess that the new line char is consumed in next cycle in:

```
(set! varA  (read-line))
```

This can be seen when you in B enter eg: 'aaa bbb' and if you display content of varA in next cycle. bbb will be there.
If you replace your read with read-line,

```
(set! varB (read-line))
```

everything works as expected.

Comment: So this means, I have to consume the new line char in varB before it hits varA instead. Am I right?

Comment: it does not go into varB at all. Both function reads from (current-input-port) and I think (not sure about it) that it reads from some internal buffer. Newline char stays in buffer and is ready to be read. So you need to flush that buffer somehow before you are setting VarA. E.g. by calling (read-line) without setting it to variable.